# Unresolved reference: io kotlin(UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a `flutter project` (New Project) in `Visual Studio Code`, but I am getting build error `"Unresolved reference: io kotlin(UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE)".`
Could someone help me to resolve this?

[image]